# Singularities in the punctured unit disc and square integrability

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

Let $f$ be holomorphic on the punctured unit disc, $D$. If $\int_D|f(z)|dA(z)<\infty$, then $z=0$ is either a removable singularity or a simple pole of $f$.

A similar problem is to prove or disprove that if $\int_D|f(z)|^2dA(z)<\infty$, then $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$.

I've tried using the Mean Value Property for $f$ and taking the limit as $z\to0$, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried integrating $1/|z|^2$ over the disk?

Comment: Matt E: isn't that infinity?

Answer (score 8):

The one with the $|f(z)|^2$ is simpler.  Consider the Laurent series $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n$.  By the orthogonality of the functions $e^{in\theta}$ on $[0, 2\pi]$,  we have $\int_0^{2\pi} |f(r e^{i\theta})|^2 \ d\theta = 2 \pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |c_n|^2 r^{2n}$ and $\int_D |f(z)|^2 \ dA = \int_0^1  \int_0^{2\pi} r |f(r e^{i\theta}|^2 \ d\theta \ dr$.  Since $\int_0^1  r^{2n+1}\ dr$ is finite for $n \ge 0$ and infinite for $n \le -1$, 
the only way to have $\int_D  |f(z)|^2 \ dA < \infty$ is that all the coefficients for $n \le -1$ are 0.

Comment: In the middle of the process, we kind of need to interchange the infinite series with integral, what domain did you choose to ensure the Laurent series to be convergent absolutely?

Comment: For any function that is analytic on an open annulus $a < |z| < b$, the Laurent series converges absolutely on that annulus.

Comment: so for example here we actually consider $0<|z|<1$. What i know is that then we have the Laurent series converges absolutely on $r_{1}\leq |z|\leq r_{2}$ for any $r_{1}>0$ and $r_{2}<1$. So we can restrict the annulus as $\epsilon\leq |z|\leq 1-\epsilon$, which makes our Laurent series converges absolutely and  uniformly. But then the outside integral should be then $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}$, I am not sure how to interchange $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|c_{n}|^{2}r^{2n+1}dr$$

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem, write $c_n$ as an integral around the circle of radius $r$ centred at $0$.  If $\int_D |f(z)|\ dA < \infty$, the integral of that times a certain power of $r$ for $r$ from 0 to 1 would be finite ...

Comment: You have not specified $c_n$ here?

Comment: $c_n$ are the coefficients of the Laurent series of $f$ around $0$.