# prove the removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Suppose U is a punctured disk,if f is holomorphic on U and $\int_{U}$$|f|^2$dxdy<$\infty$,prove that z=0 is a
removable singularity

it is obvious to prove f is bounded. however. I do not know where to do first

Comment: Holomorphic functions have Mean Value Property.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy,yes and is bounded on any compact subset. this still can not prove the f is bounded near the neighbor of 0

Comment: Integral of $|f|^{2}$ over any disk conatined in $U$ is bounded by the integral over the whole of $U$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy.i am sorry I still don't know. cause we can not use the Cauchy formula(0 is not know if it is a removable singularity)...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63472.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: You can apply the (area) mean value property to a disk of radius $|z|$, but that gives you only $|f(z)| \le C/|z|$. Of course I may have overlooked something. – The Laurent series approach from the above link seems to work.

Comment: @MartinR Your inequality is good enough. Becasue $zf(z)$ has  removable singualiry so $ f(z)$ behaves like $\frac c z$ near $0$ but the the hypotheis fails unless $c=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yes, you are right, the possibility of a simple pole can be excluded.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I wonder if the question should be answered here or closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I think it should be closed. I will now vote for closure. @MartinR